# how to bind events on ajax loaded elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, binding, stoppropagation

I am trying to load content via ajax into a container (#ajax_content). I want to be able to close (hide) the ajax loaded content (everything inside #ajax_content) when I click outside. but I want to bind the onClick of the elements inside.

HTML:

```
   <div id="wrapper"> 
      <div id="ajax_content">
      </div>
   </div>
```

HTML Loaded via AJAX:

```
<button id="super_hello" >Click</button>
```

HTML once ajax content is loaded Will be

```
   <div id="wrapper"> 
      <div id="ajax_content">
          <button id="super_hello" >Click</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.ajax_link').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {

            $('#ajax_content').html('');
            $('#ajax_content').append(data);

            $('#ajax_content').css({
                visibility: 'visible'
            });

        });

    });

    $('#ajax_content').click(function(event){

         event.stopPropagation();

    });

    $('#wrapper').click(function(){
        $('#ajax_content').hide();
        $('#ajax_content').html('');

        $(this).hide();
    });

});

    $(document).on("click","#super_hello",function(e){
        alert('clicked'); // I can't get this to work
    });
```

Problem: 
If I comment

```
$('#ajax_content').click(function(event){

     event.stopPropagation();

});
```

the event gets bind to super_hello, but then any click inside ajax_content will propagate to the wrapper which closes ajax_content.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out any clicks from the content directly in you click handler for the wrapper, something like :

```
$('#wrapper').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#ajax_content').length) {
        $('#ajax_content').hide();
        $('#ajax_content').html('');
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

will check if there is a parent element with the `#ajax_content` ID, which the wrapper does not have, but the content inside the wrapper does have.

On the other hand, as long as the wrapper and content does not have a specific size set, most likely the content fills the entire wrapper, and no click will ever be registered on the wrapper aynway, see [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/smYwm/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes actually the wrapper is set as absolute positioning with 100% height and 100% width. My bad I didn't include all the CSS that goes with it.

Comment: For some reason, this example (especially the fiddle) really succinctly summarizes binding very clearly.  Maybe it just clicked for me tonight, but it really helped!